# How to use placeholder like {app} or {temp} in Inno Setup script?

Tags: inno-setup

How can I access (directory) constants from Inno Setup script code ?

I have tried the following without success:

```pascal
function dbExistis() : Boolean;
begin
  Result := FileExists({commonappdata} + '\LR-International\DB_LR.IB');
end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`ExpandConstant` function](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_expandconstant)

```pascal
function dbExistis() : Boolean;
  begin
    Result := FileExists(ExpandConstant('{commonappdata}') + '\LR-International\DB_LR.IB');
  end;
```

Comment: It's best to incude the full path in the `ExpandConstant()` call as it handles addition and potential duplicate `\` characters.

Answer (score 5):

Use the [`ExpandConstant`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_expandconstant.htm) function to expand any of the constants value:

```pascal
function dbExistis: Boolean;
begin
  Result := FileExists(ExpandConstant('{commonappdata}\LR-International\DB_LR.IB'));
end;
```

Comment: You're welcome! Anyway, follow [Deanna's suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14478105/how-to-use-placeholder-like-app-oder-temp-in-innosetup-pascal-scripting/14478158#comment20173315_14478172) and expand the full path as I shown in this post rather than expanding just the constant portion as shown in the accepted answer.